# Integrating Spring Security into Grails Using Netbeans IDE

Tags: java, grails, spring-security

Am trying to integrate `Spring security` into a Grails Web application using `NetBeans IDE`.

Steps were:

1. added  `mavenRepo "http://repo.spring.io/milestone"`  to `repository`
2. `compile ":spring-security-core:2.0-RC2"`  to `plugins`.

When I try `grails s2-quickstart com.zot.auth User Role` in cmd prompt I get below error. Can anyone help. Also would like to know if we can create the spring security files directly in NetBeans like we create the pojos I mean without using a commandline.

```
| Error Error generating web.xml file (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)
```

Comment: did you use --stacktrace to see the full trace ? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I faced same problem and resolved using following steps:

```
grails clean
grails refresh-dependencies
```

If still not work then remove `target` folder.

Comment: Thanks user1690588. It worked finally!. But din know the reason behind it. Also the second solution u had given if i delete the target folder. Will it reproduce during compile time? Am new to grails folder struction.

Comment: It is recommended in 2.3.x version of grails that you should run grails clean and grails refresh-dependencies after installing plugin.